# Bernoulli equation constant for water waves

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

A fluid fills $\{(x,y,z) \in\mathbb{R}^3:y \leq0\}$. The flow $\textbf{u}=(u,v,w)$ is given by $u=k\sin(\omega t)\cos(kx)e^{-|k|y}$, $v=-|k|\sin(\omega t)\sin(kx)e^{-|k|y}$, $w=0$, for $y\leq0$. We assume no gravity/body forces, and the flow is irrotational, unsteady, and incompressible, so we may use Bernoulli's equation in the form:

$$\nabla\left(\frac{1}{2}\rho|\textbf{u}|^2 + p +\rho\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}\right)=0$$

where $\phi$ is the vector potential, $\rho$ is the constant density.

This tells us that $\frac{1}{2}\rho|\textbf{u}|^2 + p +\rho\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}$ does not vary in space, i.e. is constant. In the example in the textbook, this is simply rearranged to give

$$p = -\frac{1}{2}\rho|\textbf{u}|^2-\rho\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}$$

I do not understand why we can assume the constant is 0, and rearrange for this, instead of having that

$$p = C-\frac{1}{2}|\textbf{u}|^2-\rho\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}$$

where $C$ is a constant. Why do we have the freedom to just say that the constant is $0$?

Comment: Depending on the context, $C$ may not be physically relevant. For example, the momentum equation only depends on the gradient of pressure $\nabla p$ as opposed to $p$ itself, so in that context there is no difference between $p$ and $p + C$. Moreover, Bernoulli's principle is valid only along streamlines, and each streamline has a different $C$, so perhaps the author of your book is arbitrarily considering the streamline in which $C = 0?$ More information is needed to fully answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the derivative of a constant is zero, once the gradient operator is removed there will be a constant on the rhs of the equation. That constant when subtracted from the other constant which appears from the integration of the lhs are assumed to cancel.

I am not an expert but it intuitively made sense to me that way.

Comment: I'm unclear why there are two constants. Removing the gradient operator and integrating both sides are the same step (I mean you remove $\nabla$ by integrating), so won't there be just one constant?

Comment: Integrating both sides will yield a constant on each side since there are 2 integrals being computed.